# Why don't we check the condition variable at signal producer rather than consumer?

Tags: locking, signals, condition-variable

As far as I know, the consumers are to check the condition variable when they're waiting for the signal.

```
Consumer:
lock.Lock()
while(condition) {
    cond.Wait()
}
lock.Unlock()

Producer:
lock.Lock()
changeCondition()
cond.Signal() or cond.Broadcast()
lock.Unlock()
```

Why can't it be:

```
Consumer:
lock.Lock()
cond.Wait()
lock.Unlock()

Producer:
lock.Lock()
changeCondition()
if(condition) {
    cond.Signal() or cond.Broadcast()
}
lock.Unlock()
```